# Rendering particular component in v-for

Tags: filter, vue.js

I want to render particular component in v-for based on the category present in the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [Dynamic Components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components).

> You can use the same mount point and dynamically switch between multiple components using the reserved  element and dynamically bind to its is attribute:

**Demo Code:**

```
<span v-for="category in categories">
  <component :is="category.name"></component>
</span>
```

You also need to register this components globally or in a component you are using.

Comment: You should add that the components need to be registered either globally or on the component level.

Comment: @JustinMacArthur Thanks